# Class initialization as static final

Tags: java

I wanted to know if it is a good practice to initialize builder classes in a single class declared as static final for directly access?, since I am using them on some classes, here is an example.

```
public class LoaderTypes {

    public static final Loader MS_WORLD = new Loader.Builder(LoaderType.MS_WORLD).
            prioritizeWith(1000).
            schedule().
            build();

    public static final Loader PDF = new Loader.Builder(LoaderType.PDF).
            prioritizeWith(1000).
            schedule().
            build();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question but you might wanna do lazy loading to improve application loading time. Make `MS_WORLD`  private. Create a public static `getMSWorldLoader` method and build the loader if the variable is null.

Comment: Or use [static lazy initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420504/threading-lazy-initialization-vs-static-lazy-initialization) - which is thread safe too - although you need to be careful not to have anycalls from the static initializer class back to anything static in the outer, or you can get well defined wierd shit.